# recommended way to launch an activity from a non-activity class

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, start-activity

I have an activity contains expandable list in its layout, the expandable list fle extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. and what i want to so is, when an item
in the list is clicked a new activity should starts containg the clicked item data.

my question is, what is the recommended way to launching the new activity when an item is clicked, should i launch the new activity from the listener in the class 
that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter or i should handle that from the activity itself through an interface passes a flag for an example from the listenr to the
activity?

Comment: that's basically just a question of good class design, not android specific. So [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) et al applies.

Answer (score 1):

Well I usually do this by using an interface between the class and the owner activity. I would assume though that there isnt much a difference between the methods. It just seems cleaner to use an interface as oppose to passing a reference to the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Responsibility of your `BaseExpandableListAdapter` should not be handling events as its a data adapter. you should route your events to activity and handle them over there as you said in your second option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the intent for the launching the activity from the non-activity class.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but i know that i can do it via intent from a non activity class , but i asked about the recommended way